# When is it necessary to convert confidence intervals as per this link?

Tags: pearson-r, spearman-rho

I have this link

http://onlinestatbook.com/2/estimation/correlation_ci.html

Where they mention taking Pearson's $r$ and using the Fisher transformation and standard error to convert confidence intervals. Is the always necessary with Pearson's $r$? Is the process the same for Spearman's $\rho$?

Comment: That's how you calculate confidence intervals for a correlation. What do you get if you don't convert confidence intervals?  (Spearman correlation is trickier.)

Comment: According to Wiki you can do the same thing for Spearman. Is this not true?

Comment: I didn't know that.